# Set default serializer for user in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-users

I created a rest-framework API in django for signup and its serializer is like this:

```
class SignupSerializer(ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name')
    read_only_fields = ()

def create(self, validated_data):
    with transaction.atomic():
       new_user = User.objects.create_user(....)
       return new_user
```

Now its working perfectly fine, but `problem is that it also returns password hash` in response object.
Or if i include `user` in any other serializer and set `depth=1` it still returns every field including `password`

How can I set default serializer for user? so that it only returns those fields which I set by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django Rest Framework fields can be configured to be "write only". The documentation even has an example that pretty much covers your usecase:

```py
class CreateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'username', 'password']
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User(
            email=validated_data['email'],
            username=validated_data['username']
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments

Comment: the fine print: "if the field has already been explicitly declared on the serializer class, then the extra_kwargs option will be ignored."

Answer (score 0):

Try to use diferent serializers, like one for create(post) and another one for read(get).

In the get serializer, exclude the password field.